# Deleting Rows from InnoDB is very slow

Tags: mysql

Because I can not use Truncate (just delete a small part of the data), the data in this table is required to retain only the data of the day, so every time at some time in the morning when other programs to process the data, delete the previous table Data, deleting deletes millions of records in the table using `delete`, MySQL deletes very slowly Every 10,000 records take about 4 minutes or so, it is unacceptable to delete all useless data for more than eight hours . .

somebody told me that each time you delete a record, the database updates the index accordingly, which is a very slow I / O operation, and the more fragmented the index is, the slower it becomes.
I take it to delete the index and then delete the data and then rebuild the index method, and did not find the deletion speed has improved, but from time to time it occurs :'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction'

table info:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbplaylog_copy` (
  `Pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Company_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '??id',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '"??ID"',
  `Devno` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT '????',
  `Ad` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '????',
  `MakeTime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '????',
  `LastTime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '??????',
  `StartTime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '???????(0,24*60)',
  `EndPoint` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '????????(0,24*60)',
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '???1-????0-???',
  `Note` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '????',
  `Valid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '???',
  `Type` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0,???1????2???',
  `PlayStartTime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PlayEndTime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DownloadTime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DeleteTime` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TemplateId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ad_adnum` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '???ad_id',
  `length` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DownloadPercent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '???????',
  `DownloadSuccess` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '\r\n0-??\r\n1-??”',
  `Playlist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1???',
  `Reset` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1???',
  `source` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `distribute` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-2' COMMENT '0??-2??',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Pid`),
  KEY `starttime` (`StartTime`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Devno` (`Devno`),
  KEY `playstarttime` (`PlayStartTime`),
  KEY `index_playlist_id` (`Playlist_id`),
  KEY `ad` (`Ad`),
  KEY `company_id` (`Company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8760113 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

query Statement：

```
 DELETE FROM tbplaylog WHERE tbplaylog.StartTime < ? OR tbplaylog.StartTime > ? ORDER BY Pid LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Why can't you use truncate? It looks a valid solution for your situation. You may be able to do it shortly before or after midnight (maybe depending on when data is added/used). You may also use partitioning by day, which would allow you to more easily truncate (a whole partition, so a whole day). Also, you have added a `select` as a query, but it's unclear how it relates to your problem with deleting data.

Comment: Have you tried 
DELETE FROM tbplaylog WHERE tbplaylog.StartTime <> ? ORDER BY Pid LIMIT 10000

Comment: Also, consider removing the order by.

Comment: And finally, have you performed an 'analyze' to see what's going on? See [tuning mysql queries](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/tune-mysql-queries-performance/)

Comment: @Solarflare thanks。maybe i should try to partition the table.

Comment: @Tom Drake sorry, the first '?' and the last '?' are different one

Comment: How do you get dates larger than "today" into your table (so you have to delete them with `> StartTime`)? Maybe consider not adding data that you do not need in the first place. Up to now I thought that you continuously add several million rows for the current day (not the future), and during adding, you need to delete the rows from last day (which partitioning might be perfect for if it doesn't interfere with your data model). If that's not the case you should clarify. Also, Tom is right, you don't need `order by` (check `explain delete ...` to see if it uses the primary key or starttime).